# App not responding for ACTION_PICK after selecting image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I have an activity in my library project. From that activity, I am trying to get an image from library. 1 out of thousand times(metaphor), the code below works fine. But mostly, after selecting an image , application gets stuck at black screen.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 intent.setType("image/* video/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

**LOG**

This is the success scenario :

```
06-22 11:22:16.559 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: onCreate
06-22 11:22:16.869 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: onResume
06-22 11:22:24.949 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: Before startActivityForResult
06-22 11:22:24.959 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: After startActivityForResult
06-22 11:22:32.359 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: RESULT onActivityResult
06-22 11:22:32.429 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: onResume
```

After this, I tried again, then just these two logs, and then stuck

```
06-22 11:23:02.919 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: Before startActivityForResult
06-22 11:23:02.929 19038-19038/com.xyz D/SELECT_IMAGE: After startActivityForResult
```

**EDITED :  log I got with `adb shell dumpsys activity top`**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.getDumpActivitiesLocked(ActivityStack.java:6544)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.getDumpActivitiesLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:5734)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dumpActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:17777)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dump(ActivityManagerService.java:16936)
    at android.os.Binder.dump(Binder.java:334)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:292)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:2568)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3242)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:461)
```

Comment: The same code is working fine in an other standalone application i.e. not in a library project.

Comment: where is it "stuck"? did you add some logging?

Comment: App goes to Photos App -> Select Image -> Black...
I have tried logging in my `onActivityResult` but the app never returns back to `onActivityResult`

Comment: add `Log.d` before / after calling `startActivityForResult` and in `onCreate` /  `onStart`  / `onResume`

Comment: @pskink , I have updated my question with the log.

Comment: when "stuck at black screen" run `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Comment: error: device not found

Comment: device not found? so where are you running your apk?

Comment: Obviously in my mobile, but as u said, when the app stucks and If I run this command, this is the result I am getting

Comment: so `adb devices` shows the same? did you connect your device via usb or some other means?

Comment: no, adb logcat starts showing hugeee results

Comment: what about `adb devices` ? does it show `device not found `?

Comment: adb devices show this : list of attached devices, and then the device

Comment: so how come you got `device not found`? try running `adb shell dumpsys activity top` again

Comment: the result I extracted from this is that the system (android) is not keeping track of my activity. @pskink, can u please help

Comment: did you try for testing to narrow it down by `intent.setType("image/*");` or `intent.setType("video/*");`? are there any differences?

Comment: yes, same result. the thing is, when I it opens the photos app, I accidently hit up icon (back arrow at top) and the same thing happened. from that I am assuming the system is not keeping track of my activity from where the intent started

Comment: May be because the intent is originating from a library project. ???

Comment: in such cases watch the logcat carefully: `adb logcat`, it has to show something interesting

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with library project. I started same intent from app project and same thing happened

Comment: Did you see the logcat?

Comment: Yes, it is just stuck..

Comment: what stuck? does your device respond? or you have to reboot it?

Comment: black screen, app stops responding, and i have to kill the app forcefully by pressing home and recents key of my mb.

Comment: so what is shown on the logcat just after you call `startActivityForResult`? your device is still alive so there must be something on the logcat, just make sure you run `adb logcat` from the terminal window, and not any android studio "logcat" window wich can filter out some logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115288/discussion-between-bst-kaal-and-pskink).

Answer (score -1):

Use this  with  on activityResult  like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final static int REQUEST_GALLERY=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/* video/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Recieved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     if (requestCode==REQUEST_GALLERY)
    {
        if(responseCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thnx, but the issue is, the app gets stuck even before coming back to `onActivityResult`

Comment: Please check ur  request code and  the  location where u  have  used the code for  startActivityforResult .   Its  working  perfectly  here